# SQL Server interpreting 2 Unicode characters as the same

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2019 at the moment but would like this to work in all versions, and need to store strings with different unicode values. One string has `0xC3 0x89`, and the other has `0x45 0xCC 0x81`. The rest of the characters are the same.

```
testÉ
testÉ
```

I am using `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8` collation, column is of datatype `nvarchar`, and I am prefixing the strings with `N`.

Can anyone tell me how to insert these so that SQL Server stores them as different?

```
INSERT INTO directory (directory_id, full_path) 
VALUES (1, N'testÉ');

INSERT INTO directory (directory_id, full_path) 
VALUES (2, N'testÉ');
```

When I try to select one or the other:

```
SELECT directory_id, full_path 
FROM directory 
WHERE full_path = N'testÉ'

SELECT directory_id, full_path 
FROM directory 
WHERE full_path = N'testÉ'
```

I end up getting both.

Comment: I'm assuming this is likely something similar to how TSQL is not case sensitive. Most likely if you turn on case sensitivity it will also make this work as expected.

Comment: Seems like you're using a CI and AI collation (Case Insensitive and Accent Insensitive).

Comment: I have tried all combinations of CI/CS and AS/AI, and the results are the same.  I have also tried with WS(width sensitivity).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Latin1_general_100_BIN2` is working the way I would expect.